# How do I find the value of an undefined CSS attribute with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to return, say, the width or height of a certain element without having set them beforehand with CSS or HTML. Is that even possible? Do you *always* have to set those before you can use them?

Comment: no you can get the effective renderd height and width... i think the properties differ cross browser. Its been awhile since ive done it without jQuery.

Comment: How is this a [dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilemma)? This is not a dilemma.

Comment: Go troll somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getComputedStyle() method on the element. There are some little differences across browsers on how this method works, but for the height and width properties it works the same.

So, an example would be:

```
var el     = document.getElementById('el'),
    height = el.getComputedStyle('height'),
    width  = el.getComputedStyle('width');
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/7Qr83/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the computed width and height of any element.

http://api.jquery.com/height/ 
http://api.jquery.com/width/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It definitely helps, but I was looking for a more... non-JQuery solution.  Not that I won't TOTALLY use Jquery for it all the time.  I just want to be able to make my own objects that do it also.

Comment: Maybe try element.style.height? I'm not sure if that actually works or not if you haven't specifically set the height in the css.